# Is the language L regular?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Could you tell me if the language $L=\{a^ib^j:i+j=k, k \geq 2 \}$ is regular? Do I have to find a regular expression for this language? Or what can I do to check if $L$ is regular or not?

Comment: I'm confused what $k$ is. Is it a parameter of the language (constant)? If yes, $L$ is finite, if not, $L = aaa^*b^*|aa^*bb^*|a^*bbb^*$.

Comment: $k$ is the sum of $i$ and $j$, a number greater than $2$... In other words $i+j \geq 2$. So that means that $L$ is not finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L$ is almost $a^*b^*$, except that $\epsilon$, $a$ and $b$ aren't in it. Regular languages are closed under difference, so $L$ must be regular.

Regular expressions don't have complement or difference, so you have to enumerate the options that *are* available. Luckily, all words of length $2$ are fine so you only need to think about the first two characters. They can only be $aa$, $ab$ or $bb$, so the expression is $aaa^*b^*|abb^*|bbb^*$.

Comment: So except from the regular expression, I can say that $L$ is regular beacause it can be writen as difference of regular languages, $L=\{a^* b^*\}-\{\epsilon\}-\{a\}-\{b\} $ ?

Comment: @MaryStar, right. $L = \{a^ib^j|i+j\geq 2\} = a^*b^*-\{a^ib^j|i+j<2\}$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your help!